# drf-spectacular request body schema field description

Tags: drf-spectacular

I'm struggling to find a way to add a field description to my request body fields, they are picked up by the serializer definion just fine but I would like to add a description line to better explain what the field should be. I can easily do this for query parameters using `parameters=[OpenApiParameter()]` etc. but I'm not finding any solution to add it for a payload field.

I've tried adding examples, parameter definitions, overriding the serializer with an inline seralizer, adding a @extend_schema_field on the field in the seralizer but that doesn't take a description param, no place seems to allow a field description.

[here is an image is showing what is currently loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keuhA.png). As you can see I have also added an example but that doesn't cover what I would like to do. Any help is appreciated